# How to move forward and backward by one word in embedded local terminal

Tags: pycharm, webstorm

Does anyone know what is the keyboard key to jump between word to word in embedded local terminal for WebStorm or PyCharm?

I have use **Option (Alt) key + Arrow Left/Right** to jump between word in Mac or mac terminal, but when I turn on embedded local terminal in WebStorm it just show `[D` or `[C`.

Searching lots online, cannot find a better solution but only find that may be the issue for WebStorm/PyCharm about meta key and `Esc`.

Comment: `Ctrl + Arrow Left/Right` works in the `Python Console`, but surprisingly doesn't work on the `Terminal` invoked with `Alt + F12` (for anyone confusing the console with the terminal like I did)

Comment: I have Mac so in Pycharm Python Console, it works to move switch between word by `Option (Alt) key + Arrow Left/Right` as well...but just not embedded terminal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm glad you brought this up because I've been wanting to fix the problem for a long time now but kept forgetting! The solution I came up with is manually adding the key binding directly to the .bash_profile. Here's a walk through:

Open .bash_profile using nano or whatever (editor you want to use) by running:

`nano ~/.bash_profile`

Then paste where ever you want in the .bash_profile these commands:

`bind '"\e\e[C": forward-word'
bind '"\e\e[D": backward-word'`

Press `^x` (that is the control key and the x key) > `y` > `enter` to save the .bash_profile changes.

Once that's finished, restart the terminal in WebStorm/PyCharm and enjoy!